# help to understand past participle

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

What type of sentence is this? Why do we use the Past Participle?

I took this sentence from a game (*Call of duty black ops 2*).

> Get the party started with a random rotation of Gun Game, Stick and Stones, One in the chamber, and Sharpshooter.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the verb phrase  **to get {something}{verbed or verbing}** to mean "to cause something or someone to enter the state expressed by the present-participle, or to achieve the state expressed by the past-participle".

> To get the large car rolling, it took the three of us pushing.
>
> To get the party started, she turned on some dance music.
>
> To get the dinner cooking, he turned on the burner to preheat the
>   skillet.
>
> To get us thinking, the teacher posed a hypothetical.
>
> To get the champagne chilled, the waiter put it in a bucket of ice.
>
> To get the problem solved, she phoned the senator.
>
> To get the term paper written, he pulled an all-nighter.
>
> To get the news circulated, they posted it on Twitter.

With the past-participle form, only verbs which take a noun-phrase direct object may be used.

With the present-participle, the verb may be intransitive.